# Removing the ".1" part in the numbering of a remark, if it is the unique remark following some theorem

Tags: numbering, theorems, amsthm, thmtools

I'm using the `amsthm` package and `thmtools` package to format my manuscript.

I'm numbering remarks within theorems, that is, having **Remark 2.1.**, **Remark 2.2.** and so on after **Theorem 2**.
However, when only one remark is made after, say, **Theorem 1**, I hope it can be numbered as **Remark 1.** instead of **Remark 1.1**.

By using the option `numbered=unless unique` in `thmtools`, the numbering can be eliminated completely, getting **Remark**. This is not what I really desire because I hope I can refer to the remark later conveniently by its numbering, instead of saying something like "*the remark made after Theorem 1*".

Below is an MWE, where I am stuck and wondering if there is any quick adaptation to realize my purpose. Thank you in advance for possible solutions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\declaretheorem[numberwithin=thm, name=Remark, numbered=unless unique]{rmk}


\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
This is a theorem.
\end{thm}

\begin{rmk} % only one remark made
This is the only remark, so number it the same as the previous theorem.
What I want is Remark 1., instead of Remark. or Remark 1.1.
\end{rmk}

\begin{thm}
This is the second theorem.
\end{thm}

\begin{rmk} % Multiple remarks
Multiple remarks follow, and this is the first.
\end{rmk}
\begin{rmk}
Since there are multiple remarks made, all of them are numbered.
\end{rmk}
\begin{rmk}
The style is Remark 2.1., 2.2., and 2.3., etc.
\end{rmk}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Could you define two `remark`-like environments, one that gerates composite numbers (such as 4.1, 4.2, etc,) and the other that generates "simple" numbers (e.g., 2, 3, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

You can define the behavior you want "by hand" using the `unique` package. The following just emulates what `thmtools` does with `numbered=unless unique`, but rather than making the remark unnumbered if unique, it sets `\thermk` to `\thethm`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[unq]{unique}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\declaretheorem[numberwithin=thm, name=Remark]{rmk}

\addtotheorempreheadhook[rmk]{%
  \setuniqmark{rmk.\thethm}%
  \ifuniq{rmk.\thethm}
    {\def\thermk{\thethm}}
    {}%
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
This is a theorem.
\end{thm}

\begin{rmk} % only one remark made
This is the only remark, so number it the same as the previous theorem.
What I want is Remark 1., instead of Remark. or Remark 1.1.
\end{rmk}

\begin{thm}
This is the second theorem.
\end{thm}

\begin{rmk} % Multiple remarks
Multiple remarks follow, and this is the first.
\end{rmk}
\begin{rmk}
Since there are multiple remarks made, all of them are numbered.
\end{rmk}
\begin{rmk}
The style is Remark 2.1., 2.2., and 2.3., etc.
\end{rmk}

\begin{thm}
bla
\end{thm}

\begin{rmk}
more bla
\end{rmk}

\end{document}
```

[image: theorems]

---

It's not too hard to define a key that has the same effect.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\makeatletter
\define@key{thmdef}{uniquewithparent}{%
  \setkeys{thmdef}{parent=#1}
  \RequirePackage[unq]{unique}
  \addtotheorempreheadhook[\thmt@envname]{%
    \setuniqmark{\thmt@envname.\csname the#1\endcsname}%
    \ifuniq{\thmt@envname.\csname the#1\endcsname}
      {\@xa\def\csname the\thmt@envname\endcsname{\csname the#1\endcsname}}
      {}%
    }
  }
\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\declaretheorem[uniquewithparent=section]{lemma}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\declaretheorem[name=Remark,uniquewithparent=thm]{rmk}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\begin{lemma}
Some text.
\end{lemma}

\begin{thm}
This is a theorem.
\end{thm}

\begin{rmk} % only one remark made
This is the only remark, so number it the same as the previous theorem.
What I want is Remark 1., instead of Remark. or Remark 1.1.
\end{rmk}

\begin{thm}
This is the second theorem.
\end{thm}

\begin{rmk} % Multiple remarks
Multiple remarks follow, and this is the first.
\end{rmk}
\begin{rmk}
Since there are multiple remarks made, all of them are numbered.
\end{rmk}

\section{Another section}

\begin{lemma}
More text.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
Even more text.
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

[image: with key]

Answer (score 0):

With `expl3` we can store the number of remarks following a theorem in a property list (further values will overwrite, so we obtain the maximum).

At the end of the run, these values are written in the aux file in the form

```
\rmklist{1=1,2=3,1=1,}
```

(values from the example), so at the beginning of the next run we can populate another property list that's used for the check. If the stored number is greater than 1, `.\arabic{rmk}` is used.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rmk}{Remark}[thm]
\renewcommand{\thermk}{\thethm\checkrmk}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% populate the property list for the checks
\NewDocumentCommand{\rmklist}{m}
 {
  \prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn \g_dustrain_rmk_in_prop { #1 }
 }

% check whether the number of remarks is > 1
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\checkrmk}{}
 {
  \__dustrain_rmk_check:e { \arabic{thm} }
 }

% at end of rmk, store the last value of rmk
\AddToHook{env/rmk/after}
 {
  \prop_gput:Nee \g_dustrain_rmk_out_prop { \arabic{thm} } { \arabic{rmk} }
 }

% at end document, write down the values in the aux file
\AtEndDocument
 {
  \iow_now:ce { @auxout }
   {
    \rmklist { \prop_map_function:NN \g_dustrain_rmk_out_prop \__dustrain_rmk_write:nn }
   }
 }

% variables
\prop_new:N \g_dustrain_rmk_out_prop
\prop_new:N \g_dustrain_rmk_in_prop

% internal functions
\cs_new:Nn \__dustrain_rmk_write:nn { #1=#2, }
\cs_new:Nn \__dustrain_rmk_check:n
 {
  \int_compare:nT { 0\prop_item:Nn \g_dustrain_rmk_in_prop { #1 } > 1 } { .\arabic{rmk} }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__dustrain_rmk_check:n { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
This is a theorem.
\end{thm}

\begin{rmk} % only one remark made
This is the only remark, so number it the same as the previous theorem.
What I want is Remark 1., instead of Remark. or Remark 1.1.
\end{rmk}

\begin{thm}
This is the second theorem.
\end{thm}

\begin{rmk} % Multiple remarks
Multiple remarks follow, and this is the first.
\end{rmk}
\begin{rmk}
Since there are multiple remarks made, all of them are numbered.
\end{rmk}
\begin{rmk}
The style is Remark 2.1., 2.2., and 2.3., etc.
\end{rmk}

\begin{thm}
bla
\end{thm}

\begin{rmk}
more bla
\end{rmk}

\end{document}
```

[image]